# Google Drive API to update permissions using File's Patch Endpoint

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, permissions, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

We are using Google Drive API to upload files and update permissions in our application. Requirement is to update the permissions ~60 users/groups.

There are three ways by which we can update permissions on a file :

1. Use [File's](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch) Patch Endpoint
2. Use [File's](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch) Update Endpoint
3. Use [Permissions's](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource) Insert Endpoint

If we go with #3, we have to make ~60 calls based on the permission change which is not good actually as it has to make that much http calls and it affects the quota usage.

So we tried with #1, we provide the necessary input in "permissions" key. It returns 200 but the file is not shared as per the given input.

Is there anything that I am missing ?

Comment: What exactly are you patching?  Which value?  I seam to remember a bug in permissions patch.  I need to dig in the issue forum.

Comment: I am trying to patch 'permissions'. Value permissions:[{"role":"writer","type":"user", "value":"abc@domain.com"}]

Comment: So you are getting a list of the permissions currently on the file changing X and then patching the permission back to the same file?

Comment: Have you tried permissions.patch?  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/patch

Comment: a) Upload a file b) Get the users/groups with whom file is to be shared c) Patch the permissions using the File's patch endpoint.

Comment: you cant patch permissions on a file.   you can insert permissions to the file.   you can patch the permissions of a file using permissions.patch.  but you can not update or patch the permissions directly of a file.  That would be two calls for to the api it doesn't work.

Comment: @DaImTo :( We want to share file to ~60 users & groups totally and that much http calls is too much :(

Comment: Its the only way of doing it.   You cant patch the permissions on a file directly.   you have to patch the permission itself.   (I have been there :) )  This isn't even a limitation in your client library this is ingrained in the Drive API itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Permissions.Insert` is the only way to add permissions to a file; it's not feasible via operations on the `Files` API.

The Google Drive API does however support batching, which means that instead of sending 60 separate HTTP requests, you can send a single batch that contains 60 requests. This won't help with quota, but will likely perform better. More information here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch